# Vue 2.0: Passing asynchronous data to child component

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent Vue component that passes data to its child through a prop, but the data is available asynchronously and so my child component initializes with undefined values.

**What can I do to prevent initialization until the data is available?**

**Parent:**

```
  var employees = new Vue({
    el: '#employees',
    data: { ... },
    methods: {
      fetch: function(model, args=null) {

      let url = "/" + model + ".json"
      console.log(url);
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: ((res) => {
          console.log(res)
          this[model] = res;
          this.isLoading = false;
        error: (() =>  {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }),
        complete: (() => {
          // $('.loading').hide();
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
      })

    },
    mounted: function() {
      this.fetch(...)
      this.fetch(...)
      this.fetch('appointments')
    }
  })
```

My fetch method is called multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

In the code below, I modified your `fetch` method to return the promise from the ajax call. We can then collect those promises in an array and pass them to `Promise.all` and do something when *all* of the ajax calls have completed. In this case, set the `isLoading` property so that you can use `v-if` on your child component.

```
var employees = new Vue({
  el: '#employees',
  data: { isLoading: true },
  methods: {
    fetch(model, args=null) {
      let url = "/" + model + ".json"
      const success = res => this[model] = res
      const error = err => console.log(err)
      return $.ajax({url, success, error})
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    let promises = []
    promises.push(this.fetch('stuff'))
    promises.push(this.fetch('otherstuff'))
    promises.push(this.fetch('appointments'))
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => this.isLoading = false)
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 23):

You can just use `v-if` in your parent template:

```
<template v-if="everthingIsReady">
    <child-item :data="data"></child-item>
</template>
```

Child Item won't be created until `everythingIsReady` is set to `true` and you can set it right after all your calls complete.

Comment: my issue is that I call `fetch()` multiple times, so it'll update `everythingIsReady` with the first iteration

Comment: Simple and efficient, I like it... Thanks <3

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!